# Insert an image with JXL start as runnable jar

Tags: java, image, xls, jxl

I try to insert an image in my Excel file with JXL. Everything works fine until I export the code into a Runnable JAR file, which causes the program to generate an error (`java.io.FileNotFoundException`) when run. I have read carefully all of the above recommendations; nevertheless can't apply them to my code. I would be very grateful for any advice on how to eliminate the error in my case. Here is the code extract:

```
BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(new File(result1.class.getResource("/image/IMG1.png").toURI()));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(input, "PNG", baos);
sheet.addImage(
    new WritableImage(4, 3, input.getWidth() / CELL_DEFAULT_WIDTH,
    input.getHeight() / CELL_DEFAULT_HEIGHT,
    baos.toByteArray()
));
```

Comment: "The program generates an error" What is the error?

Comment: I think the jar-file generates a java.io.FileNotFoundException-error